# CSS grid make siblings items stretch

Tags: css

I wanna stretch the small image to the big image height like the below image:
[image]

I have tried `align-items: stretch;`, `justify-content: stretch;`, `align-content: stretch;`, `justify-items: stretch;`, and assign `height: 100%;` to the images, but all of these not working...I don't know why...

And my second question is that there should be only two rows, I don't understand why `grid-row: 1 / 2;` is not working but `grid-row: 1 / 4;` is working...

```css
#main {
  align-items: stretch;
  justify-content: stretch;
  align-content: stretch;
  justify-items: stretch;
  display: grid;
  gap: 15px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4,minmax(0,1fr));
  width: 500px;
}

#big {
  grid-column: 2 / span 2;
  grid-row: 1 / 4;
}

#main img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/500x200/e3e3e3/000000">
  <img id="big" src="https://dummyimage.com/1000x1000/e3e3e3/000000">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/500x200/e3e3e3/000000">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/500x200/e3e3e3/000000">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/500x200/e3e3e3/000000">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use `grid-area: span 2/span 2`

```css
#main {
  display: grid;
  gap: 15px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4,minmax(0,1fr));
  width: 500px;
}

#big {
  grid-area: span 2/span 2;
}

#main img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/500x200/e3e3e3/000000">
  <img id="big" src="https://dummyimage.com/1000x1000/e3e3e3/000000">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/500x200/e3e3e3/000000">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/500x200/e3e3e3/000000">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/500x200/e3e3e3/000000">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change `grid-row` from `1 / 4` to `1 / 3`:

```css
#main {
  align-items: stretch;
  justify-content: stretch;
  align-content: stretch;
  justify-items: stretch;
  display: grid;
  gap: 15px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, minmax(0, 1fr));
  width: 500px;
}

#big {
  grid-column: 2 / span 2;
  grid-row: 1 / 3;
}

#main img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/500x200/e3e3e3/000000">
  <img id="big" src="https://dummyimage.com/1000x1000/e3e3e3/000000">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/500x200/e3e3e3/000000">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/500x200/e3e3e3/000000">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/500x200/e3e3e3/000000">
</div>
```